# Usage of cautionary overlaps precautionary

Tags: word-usage

I found following example sentences on [Cambridge website](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cautionary)

> Happily, there was no need for the cautionary measure.
>
> This remark startled me, and I was prompted to make a cautionary observation

As per the meaning of the word **"cautionary"** - "giving a warning", this word doesn't appear to be a right choice here. It should be replaced by **"precautionary"**, which means **"preventive action"**.

Comment: These words have more than one meaning.  So why do you say "*the* meaning"?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I found only one meaning of these words in Oxford and Cambridge as follows: 
precautionary ADJECTIVE Carried out as a precaution; preventive.
cautionary ADJECTIVE Serving as a warning.

Comment: A **cautionary** measure is one taken in advance of some risk by someone who may be about to encounter it; a **cautionary** remark or observation may be offered  to someone who may  be about to encounter some risk.

Comment: And I think the Precautionary measures are taken in general.  If the chances of occurrence of a risk are more then one should take cautionary measure.  One should take precautionary measures in general.

Comment: The **pre** prefix of **precaution(ary)** might suggest an abundance of caution, a measure taken well in advance of any specific looming risk.  *It's only a precaution*.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example:

> Happily, there was no need for the cautionary measure.

there is no action, so *cautionary* is correct.

The second example:

> This remark startled me, and I was prompted to make a cautionary observation.

you need to specify what the observation was. It could be cautionary or precautionary.